# MySQL View, Union and Group By

Tags: mysql, sql, view, union

I'm trying to write this SQL Query:

```
Select t1.tms_id, t1.tms_name, t1.Pts from (
SELECT t.tms_id, t.tms_name, SUM(s.lsc_1stscore) as Pts FROM tb_team as t,tb_league as l, tb_game as g, tb_score as s
WHERE (t.tms_id = l.lgs_1stplace) AND (l.fk_lsc_id = s.lsc_id) AND (t.fk_gms_id = g.gms_id) AND (g.gms_id = 1)
GROUP BY t.tms_name
) t1
union
Select t2.tms_id, t2.tms_name, t2.Pts from (
SELECT t.tms_id, t.tms_name, SUM(s.lsc_2ndscore) as Pts FROM tb_team as t,tb_league as l, tb_game as g, tb_score as s
WHERE (t.tms_id = l.lgs_2ndplace) AND (l.fk_lsc_id = s.lsc_id) AND (t.fk_gms_id = g.gms_id) AND (g.gms_id = 1)
GROUP BY t.tms_name
) t2
union
Select t3.tms_id, t3.tms_name, t3.Pts from (
SELECT t.tms_id, t.tms_name, SUM(s.lsc_3rdscore) as Pts FROM tb_team as t,tb_league as l, tb_game as g, tb_score as s
WHERE (t.tms_id = l.lgs_3rdplace) AND (l.fk_lsc_id = s.lsc_id) AND (t.fk_gms_id = g.gms_id) AND (g.gms_id = 1)
GROUP BY t.tms_name
) t3
union
Select t4.tms_id, t4.tms_name, t4.Pts from (
SELECT t.tms_id, t.tms_name, SUM(s.lsc_4thscore) as Pts FROM tb_team as t,tb_league as l, tb_game as g, tb_score as s
WHERE (t.tms_id = l.lgs_4thplace) AND (l.fk_lsc_id = s.lsc_id) AND (t.fk_gms_id = g.gms_id) AND (g.gms_id = 1)
GROUP BY t.tms_name
) t4
ORDER BY Pts DESC
```

I need to add a group by at this query, specificaly before the last ORDER BY Pts DESC, but adding the GROUP BY tms_id (example), show me the same result.

A friend recommend me to create a VIEW, but when I try show me this error:

> *#1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause*

And I don't really know what is a subquery (I searched for and I didn't really understand). How can I reorganize or repair this QUERY to use the another GROUP BY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Extract.

Select t1.tms_id, t1.tms_name, t1.Pts from (
    SELECT t.tms_id, t.tms_name, SUM(s.lsc_1stscore) as Pts FROM tb_team as t,tb_league as l, tb_game as g, tb_score as s
    WHERE (t.tms_id = l.lgs_1stplace) AND (l.fk_lsc_id = s.lsc_id) AND (t.fk_gms_id = g.gms_id) AND (g.gms_id = 1)
    GROUP BY t.tms_name
) t1
```

the following is a sub query from the sql statement above.

```
   SELECT t.tms_id, t.tms_name, SUM(s.lsc_1stscore) as Pts FROM tb_team as t,tb_league as l, tb_game as g, tb_score as s
    WHERE (t.tms_id = l.lgs_1stplace) AND (l.fk_lsc_id = s.lsc_id) AND (t.fk_gms_id = g.gms_id) AND (g.gms_id = 1)
    GROUP BY t.tms_name
```

To use subqueries within mysql views make each subquery into a view and then use that view instead of a subquery.

Comment: Thanks man! Your explanation cleared all for me, and now all are working perfectly!!